# switching from implementation to ADTS

Tags: java, class, hash, collections

Hi im new to ADTS and im trying to convert this file from a implemented version to just using the collection as practice

```
   import java.util.HashMap;
   public class HashConvert
   {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        HashMap <String, Object> capCity = new HashMap<String, Object>(20);

        String[] data = {"Darwin", "Sydney", "Melbourne", "Brisbane", "Canberra", "Hobart",   "Perth"};

        for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            
            capCity.tab(data[i], "O"+data[i]);
        }
```

Im trying to edit it to use all HashMaps methods from the collections,
I have already written a class that is implemented similar to a "hashMap" but i dont want to use it any more, want to use the ADT's methods
The "tab" function does not seem to be working and comes up with the identifier required.
i tried doing an override method but it doesn't work

thank you